# Using FB JS sdk for user authentication in react-native

Tags: facebook-graph-api, reactjs-native

I am aware of native [`ios`](https://github.com/magus/react-native-facebook-login) solution. I am wondering if it is possible to use [`FB JS sdk`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.3) in `react-native` to login the users. A sample code to load FB SDK below - it will throw error in `react-native` because `document` doesn't seem to be a valid object in that implementation.

```
(function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_LA/sdk.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

I can also use `oauth2` manual login flow but using `FB JS SDK` seems better because it handles other scenarios like two-factor authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the Facebook React Native SDK Login (you can find it [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk)) to do user authentication, I tried it and it works for signing users in...the ReadMe says delete sub projects, I was confused and deleted too many, and it didn't work, so I had to start over again, I would recommend keep the sub projects for now until we find out exactly which sub projects to delete...